# Dynamics CRM deployment issue

Tags: deployment, dynamics-crm-2015

We are trying to deploy our unmanaged solution from our development system as a managed solution to our production system, as we do regularly.

We are now getting a deployment failure: the deployment rolls back. I download the deployment report: It shows that all entities and diagrams are deployed and that the dashboards (next item on the list) were not started. No issue is shown.

Then I run a trace on the server. It shows a "duplicate key" exception: "inserted element already exists". But there is no real indication which record is causing the conflict.

```html
Crm Exception: Message: Import failed, ErrorCode: -2147188706, InnerException: System.ArgumentException: Ein Element mit dem gleichen SchlÃ¼ssel wurde bereits hinzugefÃ¼gt.
   bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.IgnoreCustomizedReportsTreeInNonOverwriteMode.FindExistingRelations(XmlNodeList reports, Guid solutionId)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.IgnoreCustomizedReportsTreeInNonOverwriteMode.Execute(IXPathNavigable reportsRoot, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.ReportPreImportHandler.ExecutePreImportSteps(XmlNode reportsNode, ExecutionContext context)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.ImportReportsHandler.ImportItem()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.ImportHandler.Import()
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootImportHandler.ImportAndUpdateProgress(ImportHandler ih)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootImportHandler.ProcessMetadataHandlers(String[] ImportEntities, Hashtable ht, String& curPath, ImportHandler& ihForCurrentPath, CounterList listCounters)
   bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.RootImportHandler.RunImport(String[] ImportEntities)
```

Question: How do other programmers hunt this kind of issue?

It is an on-premise installation.

Comment: In general, this kind of errors are related to changes in the solution like changing a field type but the error message usually has more details too. I imagine that you're working with an OnPrem, is it possible for you to use the SQL profiler (in the SQL server) to see if you have more details when you import the solution?

Comment: We are one step further: As the code snippet indicates, there is some issue with the reports. In the solution We are now seeing all reports twice. No idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved the issue. For an unknown reason we had all Dynamics standard reports twice in our solution. They are also now present twice on the development system. Since those are managed reports, we can't delete them from the development system. But we removed them from the solution. Now deployment is working again.

There are still some open questions:
a) Why are the reports present twice on the dev system and in the solution?
b) Why is it a problem to import the reports twice to the prod system when they obviously coexist in the dev system.

Comment: upvoted, posting answers for self resolved questions always helps the community. Good future references.

Comment: The answer to (b) is that the reports will have the same ID (guid) and CRM will check the elements in the solution. That's why you were getting a duplicate-key dictionary error when trying to import the solution. No idea what happened to cause (a) though